# Slow file reading

Tags: android, file

Reading a small file (138 kb) from internal phone storage is very slow. It takes about **490 ms**. Writing the same file is done in only **70 ms**. (measured in emulator)

Any speedup suggestions?

Thanks, Alexander Miehlke, Berlin

```
private String readFromInternal(String filename) {
    try {
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = openFileInput(filename);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fileInputStream));
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            stringBuilder.append(line);
        return stringBuilder.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}

private boolean writeToInternal(String filename, String text) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fileOutputStream.write(text.getBytes());
        fileOutputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't benchmark anything on an emulator.  You *might* speed things up by making sure your BufferedReader has a relatively large buffer.  Say 4k-ish.  I did general Java tests years ago for optimal buffer size, and above 1-2k, it didn't seem to help much.

Try this on a phone.

Why reading is slower than writing is beyond me, but again, emulator is not where you want to benchmark.

You *might* try reversing the buffer location.  Put the buffer around the stream rather than the reader:

new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream, 2048)))

I assume you used a BufferedReader to be able to read by line.  Creating 2 bufferes is probably not great, so if you have a way to read lines that doesn't require the BufferedReader, you're probably better off.

Comment: I have tried it on my smartphone, but it is similar. Reading the same file needs 700ms. And writing is slow, too (1469 ms). Increasing buffer has no effect.

Comment: While those numbers are big, the phone numbers make a little more sense to me (write longer than read).  I would, as mentioned, put the BufferedInputStream before the InputStreamReader, with a minimum of 2K buffer.  If its still bad, I would do some raw read tests.  Make a large byte array, and read the whole file at once.  Forget line by line.  Remove as many variables as possible.  Run the file read several times in a loop (might need different files due to OS caching).

Comment: I've tried various approaches, and a lot of testing, but it was slow. Now I save the data (not this big files) in a database, which only takes a few milliseconds.

Answer (score -1):

Your problem is that you are reading line by line, but writing in one go. Try reading the file into a buffer in one go instead of the while loop.

Comment: Doubtful.  He's using a BufferedReader.  If the buffer is big enough, that shouldn't make much of a difference.